# Use state variable in ag grid callback not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, ag-grid

My use state variable, `query`, inside of the function `isExternalFilterPresent` never updates. I'm perplexed because the first `console.log` of `query` updates with each change of query. I think this is because I'm not quite understand the implementation of hooks.

```
let gridApi: GridApi | null = null;

const HouseholdTable = ({accountsData, aggregateEntityTable: {aggregateEntity, columnDefs}}: OwnProps & StateProps) => {

  const [isDeepDiveOpen, setIsDeepDiveOpen] = useState(false);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    gridApi && gridApi.onFilterChanged();
  }, [query]);

  if (accountsData) {

    const onGridReady = ({api}: GridReadyEvent) => {
      api.sizeColumnsToFit();
      gridApi = api;
    };

    const aggData = accountsData.aggregations[aggregateEntity];

    console.log(query); // This updates when query changes
    const isExternalFilterPresent = (): boolean => {
      console.log(query); // This never updates
      return !!query; 
    };

    const doesExternalFilterPass = (rowNode: RowNode): boolean => {
      // console.log('doesExternalFilterPass');
      return true;
    };

    return (
      <>
        <HouseholdsToolbar aggData={aggData}
          isDeepDiveOpen={isDeepDiveOpen}
          onDeepDiveToggleClick={setIsDeepDiveOpen}
          onQueryChange={setQuery}
        />
        <AgGridReact rowData={[]}
          columnDefs={[]}
          gridOptions={{
            headerHeight: 70,
            suppressFieldDotNotation: true,
            suppressHorizontalScroll: false,
            onGridReady,
            isExternalFilterPresent,
            doesExternalFilterPass
          }}
        />
      </>
    );
  } else {
    // handle loading
    return (<div>loading</div>);
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: StoreState): StateProps => {
  const {faStore: {accountsData}} = state;
  return {
    accountsData,
    aggregateEntityTable: aggregateEntityTableDummyConfig
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HouseholdTable);

export const aggregateEntityTableDummyConfig: AggregateEntityTable = {
  aggregateEntity: 'FOO',
  columnDefs: []
};
```

EDIT: Updated with the entire component.

Comment: can you add the whole component please?

Comment: @AtinSingh updated with the entire component.

Comment: I put together a code pen with a simplified (just a dummy AgGrid component) example that works with hooks but I'm unable to see what is wrong. Maybe it will still help you or someone else figure it out [working codepen](https://codepen.io/WillWillman/pen/yLLXBwX) cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not a problem with hooks. It looks like on the first rendering `AgGridReact` stores the reference to a function that you pass to `isExternalFilterPresent` and then never changes this reference on re-renders. To be more clear, `AgGridReact` stores the first 'version' of `isExternalFilterPresent` and never updates it. To fix your problem, you need to store the value of your filter in `useRef` hook.

React doc [says](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables):

> The useRef() Hook isn’t just for DOM refs. The “ref” object is a generic container whose current property is mutable and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class.

So you might think about useRef like about property in the class.

Here what you have to do:

```
const query = useRef(null);

const setQuery = (value) => {
  query.current = value;
  gridApi && gridApi.onFilterChanged();
}

const isExternalFilterPresent = (): boolean => {
  console.log(query.current); // Now it changes
  return !!query.current; 
};
```

Here an example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/example-of-aggrid-for-stackoverflow-answer-yd476)

Comment: After more investigation, I see that the callback `isExternalFilterPresent` never updates, meaning that the value for query never updates. Using a ref is the way around this. Thanks for the help!